# Should I use a schema when extracignt data from postgresql to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, schema, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark job taking data from a postgresql data base. Should i use a Schema when reading that data to optimize and making the extraction faster? (Normal when reading in data creating a schema makes the read faster as I have understood it)

The data is then converted to a pandas dataframe, in this conversion should I specify schema or is it already optimized?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a schema every time you read something with spark.

- you need (or infer) a schema for CSV, JSON
- you do not need a schema for PARQUET, AVRO, ORC, DB

Check the official doc of [`reader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) to see if you can add a `schema` option. If no, there is no need to provide a schema.

When you convert from pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe, the schema is kept. No need to add anything. Just be sure you have enough space in memory.